# Is it possible to damage a PCB by plugging an USB 5-pin header the wrong way?

Tags: pcb, usb, damage, socket

I am using a Cliff CP30100 dual USB socket to easily switch between two PCBs [(see wiring diagrams)](https://www.cliffuk.co.uk/products/usb/DualUSBinXLR24mm.pdf). On the inside, there is an USB-C to 5-pin cable for one PCB, and a Mini USB to 5-pin for the other. Both PCBs are connected to the upper and lower 5-pin male connectors on the CP30100.

I inadvertently connected the Mini USB to 5-pin cable the wrong way i.e: in the technical drawings, I connected the 1-2-3-4-empty onto the empty-4-3-2-1 male connector.

The PCB has a problem.  You can put in a programming mode and when you launch a software, it should open a new window, but nothing happens, it also overheats.

The problem is that this PCB is brand new and malfunctioned on the first try so I cannot say if it worked before or not.

Ironically this one is a replacement for another that had the same problem - and where I made the same mistake. I have another that works perfectly, and I think I also plugged it the wrong way once. (I thought there would be protection on the PCB or even in the 5-pin header to not cause damage so I didn't pay too much attention on the way I plugged it in the first time.)

Is it possible to damage a PCB by plugging a USB 5-pin header on the USB socket the wrong way?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But we don't know what is on your PCB so we don't know will it damage or not.

Comment: Well you are reversing VCC and GND so it is definitely not good. And as @Justme said we don't know your PCB so you should probably take it up with whoever designed the PCB.

Comment: According to the technical diagrams, one the socket, 1 is Vcc and 4 is Ground. So plugging the header in the wrong way would make the female-male correspondence Empty/Vcc, Ground/Data-, Data+/Data+, Data-/Ground and Vcc/Empty, so neither Ground or Vcc are connected. How can this damage the pcb?

Comment: We don't know what you mean by empty. The fifth pin is not empty, it's the metal shell of the USB connector. Which is usually connected to ground/chassis/earth. You connected 5V supply to the metal shell, right?

Comment: [This is the PCB (in red) and cable in question](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahae0xoYVwgkjSV3zxQK_LRmy6ip?e=XzoDq0), indeed both in the diagrams and looking at the header, the fifth is the earth contact, so I must have damaged the pcb.